# How do you know if a certain limit does not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do you know if a certain limit does not exist - without actually graphing it? What answer do you get that shows you there is no such limit?

Comment: What do you mean by "arithmetically"? How do you define the limit of a sequence/function?

Comment: I mean not by drawing it out.

Comment: Usually I know it doesn't exist, because I proved it does not exist :)

Comment: I would encourage you look over any of these existing questions about this topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=limit+not+exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather broad, but in general:

- In univariate calculus, if you can show that the limit from the left is not the same as the limit from the right, i.e. $\lim \limits_{x \to c^+} f(x) \ne \lim \limits_{x \to c^-}f(x)$, then it follows that the limit doesn't exist.
- In multivariable calculus, you can do the same thing but showing different values of the limit for two different *paths* to a certain point.